# Elastic Windows Effect in 13.10

Tags: effects

I had this effect activated on 13.04 but I can't see any option to enable it in compizconfig settings manager. I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 3):

You probably speak about wobbly effect. To have it, after you have installed [**CompizConfig Settings Manager**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/), you have to install [**compiz-plugins**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compiz-plugins/), and then enable **Wobbly Windows** plugin from CompizConfig Settings Manager:

[image: Enable Wobbly Windows]

Comment: This works on 32-bit Ubuntu 13.10 also